# Need help thinking through splitting lists at integer divisions in Python

Tags: python, list, numpy, insert, split

I currently have a dataset as a list of lists which I'd like to split at integer divisions, and insert new data if there is overlap. For example:

edit:The data set is always ordered ascendingly.

```
data = [[1.565888, 2.073744], [2.073744, 2.962492], [2.962492, 4.52838], [4.52838, 5.417127], [5.417127, 6.390517], [7.025337, 7.871763]]
fix_list(data)
#[[1.565888, 2.0], [2.0, 2.073744], [2.073744, 2.962492], [2.962492, 3.0], [3.0. 4.0], [4.0, 4.52838], [4.52838, 5.0], [5.0, 5.417127], [5.417127, 6.0], [6.0, 6.390517], [7.025337, 7.871763]]
```

However I'm at a loss when thinking through exactly how one might account for every situation, specifically when inserting [3.0, 4.0] as this is completely new information which did not exist in the previous list element.

Any help as always is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is your data always sorted in ascending order?

Comment: don't name your variables the same as builtin functions\objects.

Comment: what do you want to happen in the case of [3.0,4.0], also what would you want to happen with [5.3, 7.2] or will this not exist? ==> would you want [5.3,6.],[6.,7.],[7.,7.2] to be inserted? --answered my error

Comment: @user2705114-john if you notice the original data set, there is a pair: `[2.962492, 4.52838]`. This subsequently should become `[2.962492, 3.0], [3.0. 4.0], [4.0, 4.52838]`. In your hypothetical, that's exactly right.

Comment: Am i missing something, or did you actually accept the only answer with wrong results?

Comment: @M4rtini Ah, thanks. I had previously accepted John's answer, but had unchecked accidentally. I thought I had re-clicked John's answer a little while ago, but was mistaken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Update

This isn't as clean looking, but now all integer pairs are output, even if they aren't in the original data. On the other hand, now it's implemented with a recursive generator, which I think is kinda slick :)

---

This might do what you want. `int_split` is a generator which scans through the input list, yielding pairs clipped to integer boundaries if the pairs have different integer values. This algorithm leaves items like `[3.0, 4.0]` alone, since they are already on integer boundaries.

```
import math

data = [[1.565888, 2.073744], [2.073744, 2.962492], [2.962492, 4.52838], [4.52838, 5.417127], [5.417127, 6.390517], [7.025337, 7.871763], [11.1, 12.1]]

def int_split(data): 
    last_b = data[0][1] 

    for item in data: 
        a, b = item

        # First, make sure we haven't missed anything from the last loop
        if math.floor(a) - math.ceil(last_b) > 1.0:
            for x in int_split([[last_b, a]]):
                yield x

        # Did we cross an integer boundary, i.e. 
        # Is ceil(b) - floor(a) > 1.0? 
        if math.ceil(b) - math.floor(a) > 1.0: 
            # Yes, so split, making sure to include all integers between a and b

            # Find any integers in the range (and convert to floats)
            ints = [float(x) for x in range(int(math.ceil(a)), int(b))]
            for c in ints: 
                # output those values
                yield [a, c]
                a = c
            else:
                yield [a, math.floor(b)]
                yield [math.floor(b), b]
        else:
            yield item 

        # remember where we are
        last_b = b
```

This outputs:

```
[[1.565888, 2.0], [2.0, 2.073744], [2.073744, 2.962492], [2.962492, 3.0], 
 [3.0, 4.0], [4.0, 4.52838], [4.52838, 5.0], [5.0, 5.417127], [5.417127, 6.0], 
 [6.0, 6.390517], [7.025337, 7.871763], [7.871763, 8.0], [8.0, 9.0], 
 [9.0, 10.0], [10.0, 11.0], [11.0, 11.1], [11.1, 12.0], [12.0, 12.1]]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer; this is very close, although `[2.962492, 4.0], [4.0, 4.52838]` should in fact yield: `[2.962492, 3.0], [3.0. 4.0], [4.0, 4.52838]`

Comment: @JoeyDiNardo - Hopefully fixed now

Answer (score 0):

I have expanded the problem by adding the last gap into the list [7.025337, 7.871763],[12.,12.2], this has made my code a bit awkward but no modules imported

```
list = [[1.565888, 2.073744], [2.073744, 2.962492], [2.962492, 4.52838], [4.52838, 5.417127], [5.417127, 6.390517], [7.025337, 7.871763],[12.,12.2]]

newlist= []
for e in list:
    if list.index(e)>0:
        if z+1<= int(e[0]):
            while z < int(e[0]):
                newlist.append([float(z),float(z+1)])
                z += 1


    if int(e[0])==int(e[1]):
        newlist.append(e)
    elif int(e[0])<int(e[1]):
        y = int(e[0]+1)
        newlist.append( [e[0],float(y)] )
        while y < int(e[1]):
            newlist.append([float(y),float(y+1)])
            y +=1

        newlist.append([float(y),e[1]])
    z = int(e[1])
print (newlist)
```

gives:

```
[[1.565888, 2.0], [2.0, 2.073744], [2.073744, 2.962492], [2.962492, 3.0], [3.0, 4.0], 
[4.0, 4.52838], [4.52838, 5.0], [5.0, 5.417127], [5.417127, 6.0], [6.0, 6.390517], 
[6.0, 7.0], [7.025337, 7.871763], [7.0, 8.0], [8.0, 9.0], [9.0, 10.0], [10.0, 11.0], 
[11.0, 12.0], [12.0, 12.2]]
```

Comment: Ah, this did it. Thanks much John. I'm going to test with alternate data sets.

Comment: just changed the second bit to use while loop makes it more obvious what it does will try and stream line more than that, still really keen to see a phytonic answer

Comment: I found an error at `[5.417127, 6.0], [6.0, 6.390517], 
[6.0, 7.0]`

Actually, it should only add integer pairs for "in between" values. so if there is no [5.0, 6.0], it shouldn't add it

Comment: ok I misunderstood that then, out of curiosity should it be like this `[1.565888, 2.073744], [3.962492, 4.52838]` becomes a) `[1.565888, 2.],[3., 3.962492],[3.962492,4.],[4., 4.52838]` or b) `[1.565888, 2.],[2.,3.] [3., 3.962492],[3.962492,4.],[4., 4.52838]`

Answer (score 0):

```
def splitter(iterable):
    from collections import deque
    q = deque(maxlen=2)
    flatlist = (i for j in iterable for i in j)
    it = iter(flatlist)
    q.append(next(it))

    for val in it:
        if val == q[-1]: continue
        while (int(q[-1]) + 1 < val):
            q.append(int(q[-1])+1.0)
            yield [q[0], q[1]]
        q.append(val)
        yield [q[0], q[1]]

list_set = [[1.565888, 2.073744], [2.073744, 2.962492], [2.962492, 4.52838], [4.52838, 5.417127], [5.417127, 6.390517], [7.025337, 7.871763]]
print list(splitter(list_set))
#[[1.565888, 2.0], [2.0, 2.073744], [2.073744, 2.962492], [2.962492, 3.0], [3.0, 4.0], [4.0, 4.52838], [4.52838, 5.0], [5.0, 5.417127], [5.417127, 6.0], [6.0, 6.390517], [6.390517, 7.0], [7.0, 7.025337], [7.025337, 7.871763]]
```

Comment: On `q.append(next(it))` I get the error: `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable` when passing your `list_set = [[1.565888, 2.073744], [2.073744, 2.962492], [2.962492, 4.52838], [4.52838, 5.417127], [5.417127, 6.390517], [7.025337, 7.871763]]
print list(splitter(list_set))`

Comment: What python version are you using?

Comment: Can you try restarting the interpreter and try again? There should not be any problem. Maybe you have made some variable the same as the builtin iter or something along those lines.

Comment: Just did; the issue arises only after using list(splitter(list_set)); if just splitter(list_set) is used, the generator object is created without error.

Comment: Creation of the generator object wont actually run any of the code in the function. So it's no surprise it won't give errors. Do you get that same error if you try to iterate the resulting generator object?

Comment: Did you use `next` as a variable of some kind earlier?

Comment: I did; much earlier however to build a basic list with 'look-ahead' values. Here's the code `def neighborhood(iterable):
    iterator = iter(iterable)
    prev = None
    item = iterator.next()  # throws StopIteration if empty.
    for next in iterator:
        yield (prev,item,next)
        prev = item
        item = next
    yield (prev,item,None)`

The list is standalone however, and after it is generated it becomes it's own object.

Comment: That explains the error then. Again, you should not use builtin functions as variable names :P If you change that variable name and try again i'm fairly sure it would work.

Comment: what i usually do, if i can't find a more suitable name than next,max,sum etc. Is to just add a _ before that name. like `_next`. So you keep that name you want(almost), without overwriting the builtin.